# Good e-commerce platform for Java or .NET

Tags: java, .net, e-commerce

I'm looking for an e-commerce "platform" in Java or .NET that can satisfy the following requirements:

- Product / Service Management
- Customer Account Management
- Shopping Cart
- Checkout / Merchant Integration
- Localization (especially for currency)
- Coupons
- Multiple Storefronts
- Reporting
- Possible PayPal / Google Checkout Integration

The goal here is to integrate this with a RIA written in Adobe Flex. We are comfortable with writing a thin backend layer to support the Flex app, so the solution doesn't require a remotely-accessible API, rather just one that we can invoke from our own backend code.

Comment: checkout the only enterprise open source e-commerce platform [virto commerce](http://virtocommerce.com)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I used ofbiz for some projects, a joyful experience. It's now under the apache umbrella: http://ofbiz.apache.org/

From the website:

> The Apache Open For Business Project
>   is an open source enterprise
>   automation software project licensed
>   under the Apache License Version 2.0.
>   By open source enterprise automation
>   we mean: Open Source ERP, Open Source
>   CRM, Open Source E-Business /
>   E-Commerce, Open Source SCM, Open
>   Source MRP, Open Source CMMS/EAM, and
>   so on

I used it to build an ecommerce application to sell customized products to consumers. I used the webshop part, the production planning and warehouse management.

Beware that it takes some time to dig into this huge framework but depending on your actual needs it will be worth it. There is also decent commercial support by a lot of service providers.

Answer (score 8):

Look at nopCommerce - http://www.nopCommerce.com

Comment: You may also try our new .NET Enterprise eCommerce platform http://virtocommerce.com It's natively build for Azure but also has standalone installation.

Answer (score 7):

Broadleaf Commerce...  It's free, open source, and enterprise-class. Version 2.0 is simple to set up and configure out of the box. It also allows you to customize, extend, and integrate in absolutely any way that you need.  We were able to get a complex, highly customized site with a large number of custom features, including flash sales and perishable inventory, deployed to production in 6 weeks. http://www.broadleafcommerce.com

Comment: Did't they change licence? Isn't free since 5.0 version?

Answer (score 3):

[SoftSlate Commerce](http://www.softslate.com) meets nearly all of those requirements (with the exception of multiple storefronts, but you could run separate instances side by side). Full Java source code comes with the $495 Standard Edition license.

Answer (score 3):

we do java development and are using [shopizer](http://www.shopizer.com) it is a sales management software and also supports online invoicing

Answer (score 2):

The [Beerhouse](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/the-beer-house/) (OS) for .NET might be worth a look. It's an ASP.NET starter kit, however there is also a [paypal](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/paypal-ecommerce/) commerce kit that accompanies it. I'm not sure about coupons and flex integration however.

All the kits can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/).

Answer (score 2):

Websphere Commerce Supports almost all of your requirements(except paypal integration).

Comment: WebSphere commerce has PayPal now! Google!

Answer (score 1):

I tested and trust those (.Net):

[aspdotnetstorefront](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/)

[nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Asp.net E-Commerce post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973840/setting-up-ecommerce-in-asp-net/1059748#1059748) and about java my favorite is http://www.konakart.com/

Answer (score 1):

Freeblisket/Weblisket

Answer (score 0):

Both platforms good for what you are looking.

Decision is based on personal preferences and which platform you have experience.

Comment: We have deep experience with both. I'm looking for a particular pre-built solution to satisfy these requirements. Obviously either can be used to build the app from scratch. My personal preference doesn't enter into this in any way nor should it.