# asp.net ecommerce solutions

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

I'm working on several ASP.NET ecommerce projects where we're using Aspdotnetstorefront solution. It is not so bad. It has a lot of useful features, it is extensible, it is stable, but... the source code is like nightmare. If you need customize something - it becomes a problem for you, because you need to change it in several places and always keep it in mind.

Can anyone suggest some better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

roll your own? there are several start up projects available from microsoft or i have heard that dotshoppingcart is supposed to be good but i have not used it myself. I would advise diy as then you will know what is happening in the code

http://www.asp.net/community/projects look for ecommerce

Comment: What are the start-up eCommerce projects from MS? :-)

Comment: @IrishChieftain the link in the edited answer should help

Comment: @IrishChieftain if it helps you could always mark up my answer, hint hint :-)

Comment: Done... I'm slow to start on Mondays ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your choice will probably depend on whether you want c# or vb, webforms or MVC etc.

If you want webforms like aspdotnetstorefront then try

[Kartris (codeplex)](http://kartris.codeplex.com)

It's free and open source. Nopcommerce is popular if you want MVC